# connecting signals and slots with different relations

Tags: c++, qt, connect, signals-slots

First of all I'd say I'm a noob to GUI programming. I use Qt 5.4.

I came up with this code while watching voidRealms videos.

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider,SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)),ui->progressBar,SLOT(setValue(int)));
```

Obviously this connects slider movement with progressbar fill. This actually works like

progressbarfill `<-` slidermovement.

How can I make into a different relation? Like

progressbarfill `<-` (slidermovement)/2 or something like that.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you're reading [this section of the official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). I explains really well the basic concept of Signals & Slots.

Comment: Answering to your question - connect to different slot, which does the job. With Qt5 and c++11 you can use lambdas.

Comment: You can create new slot which will handle your conditions and connect it with this signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new slot for that purpose.
But in C++ 11 and Qt 5 style you can use labmdas! It is very comfortable for such short functions.
In your case:

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::sliderMoved, this, [this](int x) {
this->ui->progressBar->setValue(x / 2);
});
```